# Is there a way to get all values out of an std::unordered_map?

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have an `unordered_map` with some data in and I want to be able to save the contents to a file and retrieve the data later. I'm not interested in the key data, just the map values.

If I could get an array of the values stored in the map, that could then be written to disk easily, but I'm not sure what the best way of getting that data out is.

I have thought about using `.begin()` to get an iterator pointing to the beginning and iterate through all the buckets until all the values have been found. Surely there's a better way of doing this.

I really don't want to use boost or the like if possible.

Comment: What's so crazy about enumerating a container using an iterator?

Comment: I'm not sure what way you think would be easier than using an iterator.

Comment: Every possible solution to this problem is not fundamentally different from just using `.begin()` and iterating.

Comment: Better in what way? Prettier syntax? Somehow more efficient?

Comment: I meant prettier syntax more than anything else. 
A range-based for loop is good solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use a range-based for loop to grab the `second` off of each `pair`, then write it to file.

```
for (auto const& element : your_map)
{
    std::cout << element.second;  // Write to file or whatever you want to do
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can enumerate over a `std::unordered_map`. The order in which the key/value pairs come up during the enumeration cannot be predicted. However, you are garanteed to go through all the pairs.